# WolframAlpha functionality: Computing nested integrals

Tags: calculus, mathematica

Can wolframpalpha support the numerical calculation of the following type:

$$
\int_{x=0}^\infty f(x) e^{\int_{z=0}^\infty g(x,z)dz} dx
$$

Note that the inside integral is in such form where parameter x cannot be separated from it.

Thanks in advance

PS: The respective command would have been:

int(f(x)*exp[int(g(x,z),{z,0,Infinity})],{x,0,Infinity})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how to evaluate this type of integral in WolframAlpha.

In Mathematica, we could do this type of integral like so:

```
h[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x, z], {z, 0, Infinity}];
NIntegrate[f[x] Exp[h[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

As a concrete example:

```
h[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[Exp[-x*z^2]], {z, 0, Infinity}];
NIntegrate[Exp[-1/x^2] Exp[-x^2] E^h[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* Out: 0.262062 *)
```

However, WolframAlpha simply doesn't support this type of evaluation sequence and I don't see around the way intermediate definition.

More generally, it's really not the case that WolframAlpha supports general Mathematica  syntax.  If you need to evaluate this type of integral with any regularity, I suggest that you get Mathematica, or some general programmatic tool.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Syntactically "Integrate[]" isn't different than any other function. So, leaving out all parameter specifications, it's just

```
Integrate[f[] Exp[Integrate[]]]
```

or in more detail

```
Integrate[f[x] Exp[Integrate[g[x,z],{z,0,Infinity}]],{x,0,Infinity}]
```

I don't know if you mean "numerical calculation" literally here, but for any given function $g$ and fixed parameter $x$, the command Integrate[g[x,z],{z,0,Infinity}] will try to compute the integral. [NIntegrate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html) is a numerical integration command in Mathematica btw.

Comment: Sorry Nick, I meant in wolframalpha. Note that the inside integral is not given in closed form and is something like that: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390447/integral-involving-gauss-hypergeometric-function-power-exponential-and-bessel)

Comment: Dear Nick, the parameter x is not fixed as it is defined by the outside integral.

Comment: @dioxen: Wolframalpha understands the syntax of Mathematica, it understands it even better this way, as it doesn't has to guess what you mean. And Eighter it computes or not - with Mathematica it tries longer that's for sure. How do you define closed form btw.? Gauss Hypergeometric function is closed enought for me :) It it doesn't evaluate it to a finite form involving only fractions of polynomials, then there is a good change it doesn't work. So you'd have to plug in specific parameters $a,b,c,\dots$ and then the computation will terminate in some numeral.

Comment: @dioxen: I know that $x$ is bound by the outer integral, but you could just compute the inner integral numerically and use that function to do the outer integral. Of course, you can't do that practically in the small input line of the wolfram alpha web page. If you can't do the inner integral first and then use the resulting expression for the second intgral, then you can't do it. And if you have general parameters like $a,b,\dots$ inside the functions you start with, then you can't do *numerical* integrals. The Hypergeometric functions shouldn't scare you, they are like e.g. $\sinh$.

Comment: @dioxen: $r$ is the only parameter in this expression the other terms are bounded by the integrals. If this is expressible in terms of $x,y,z$ (it's the radius I guess), then a numeric solver should be able to do it. Maybe not the one line on the wolfram alpha web page. But I'm certain that if you formulate this e.g. in propper Mathematica symtax (or another language), then people here will evaluate it for you. Bye!